# Battery-like energy storage device made of assorted batteries?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-chemistry

I don't know what search terms to use. I'm also extremely ignorant with respect to EE.

I'd like to build a battery bank made of parts I found on the side of the road. I know different batteries can not be combined because of differing properties. Is there a way to combine different batteries to make a virtual big battery?

My naive approach is to hook up a step-up converter to each battery set and wire the outputs in parallel. However I feel this would still disproportionately exhaust some.

If anybody knows anything similar please don't hesitate to share.

Comment: This is just a terrible, terrible idea. Investing any time and energy into batteries that have unknown remaining life is just unwise.

Comment: I think the best thing you can do with batteries found on the side of the road is send them to be properly recycled. Don't just throw them away; a lot of useful stuff can be recycled from batteries, but definitely don't try to make a battery pack out of them. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Bad though the idea may be, that doesn't make it a bad question IMO. The core concept of combining different voltage sources into one is one I've also been wondering about.

Comment: Do you really mean "combine different batteries"? Or do you mean "combine different cells"? A battery is generally composed of a number of cells. For example, at 18650 Li-ion cell is a cell, but a laptop battery (multiple cells inside) is a battery. Please clarify what it is that you're starting with.

Comment: I guess I'll be working with second hand batteries for the most part, but the core idea is to make a energy storage system I can throw random energy storage devices at

Comment: @EmmanuelLopez Ehhhh. That's not a good idea. It's like throwing a bunch of random fuel into your fuel tank without knowing what they are and without specifically accommodating them specifically. The ampacity of your bank will also vary wildly as different segments of it drain empty at different times. The more difficult part is what you have omitted: how to charge them. You shouldn't even be charging batteries of the same type and brand off the same charger if they are of different age.

Comment: _Is it possible?_ Yes, but unlikely practical or economical. If all your batteries are of the same type and voltage, you will have some leeway. If not, you will need power electronics and BMSes to interface them.